# Google Sheet hide emtpy cells

Tags: google-sheets

So I have a simple formula I use for my tabletop game.
I have Player names in A2-A26 and their turn number in B2-B26
In E2 I have the formula

```
=Sort(A2:B26,B2:B26,False)
```

Now this makes a list of highest turn number on top and going down to lowest.
However it shows every player in the list as well.
Some turns only 5 players are participating. So I would like for only those 5 players to show up in the E2 cell and downwards.
The players who do not have turn number will have a blank cell in B2-B26
I have tried using filtering. But I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: If you have an example where filter wasn't working for you I can show you what you were doing wrong to make it work with the sort function, but I posted the simplest solution.

Comment: Your solution did exactly what I wanted, and much simpler. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query is the easiest way to accomplish this:

```
=query(A:B,"select * where B is not null order by B desc")
```